# XAML Hot Reload stops working after short time

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Can anyone tell me, why is XAML Hot Reload in Xamarin not working constantly but needs to be restarted?

When I debug and run my Xamarin project in Visual Studio and Android emulator, it works fine, but after a couple of seconds, it stops working and no longer updates, when I make a change in XAML code.

For example, when I start debugging and set a control with a property `backgroundColor="Red"`, it shows red correctly in the emulator, and I can change it to `backgroundColor="Green"` and it shows the change fine, but after some short time, like 30 seconds or so (haven't timed it exactly), it stops updating, so if I change to `backgroundColor="Yellow"`, for example, it's not updated and reflected in the emulator. I need to restart the debugging, and then the yellow color displays fine.

It doesn't matter, what my code is or what change I make, it stops working after a short time.

Why does XAML Hot Reload not works for more than a couple of seconds??

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Here is my Android emulator:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other emulators？

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT Yes, I have tried to create a new Android emulator in Xamarin, but it is the same :-(

Comment: Check this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#known-limitations)